# Jquery Load particular Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Modal. I have created common function to create modal dialog.

Below is the code

```
function createDialogWithClose(sourceDivId, url, targetDivId)
{
    var dialog = jQuery(sourceDivId).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui){
            jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        },
        close:function(event,ui){
            jQuery(targetDivId).load(url + " " +targetDivId);

        }

});

}
```

Now inside the dialog, I am perfoming some operation which need to reflect in the parent page.

So on close I have written to load that div. which on request set parameter in `init()` method and on loading it displays new result.

But problem is div get inside the div

Any other way to obtain above steps?

Comment: where do you want the loading div to be?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to use $.ajax request

```
function createDialogWithClose(sourceDivId, url, targetDivId)
{
    var dialog = jQuery(sourceDivId).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui){
            jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        },
        close:function(event,ui){

           $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: "POST",
           data: "",
           cache: true,
           success: function(response){
                  $("#targetDivId").html(response);           
           }
           });
        }

});

}
```

Comment: I dont want to load all the response, I want to load particular Div of the response